# T-SQL & Xquery - changing literal value to use reference to none does not return result

Tags: sql-server, xml, attributes, xquery

I hope someone can help me:

This column returns the value I require based on `DTS:ObjectName="vSQL_ASN"` attribute within my xml:

```
col.value('(//DTS:Variables/DTS:Variable[@DTS:ObjectName=**''vSQL_ASN''**]/DTS:VariableValue)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
```

However when I replace 'vSQL_ASN' to use a look up from another xpath query that i know evaluates exactly to 'v_SQl_ASN' I get Null returned.

```
col.value('(//DTS:Variables/DTS:Variable[@DTS:ObjectName = **substring((./properties/property[@name="SelectStatement"])[1],9,string-length(substring((./properties/property[@name=''SelectStatement''])[1],8,50))-2)]/DTS:VariableValue**)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
```

Can anyone please help why this is the case?

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:refId="Package"
  DTS:CreationDate="2/16/2013 1:09:40 PM"
  DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:CreatorComputerName=""
  DTS:CreatorName=""
  DTS:DTSID="{47964379-22CB-4CC3-A5CD-3D01A1B8565C}"
  DTS:EnableConfig="True"
  DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="15.0.1100.123"
  DTS:LocaleID="2057"
  DTS:ObjectName="1118_WMOS_Intk_FV"
  DTS:PackageType="5"
  DTS:VersionBuild="169"
  DTS:VersionGUID="{C43BDFD3-ED85-482F-8065-C07332E04CD1}">
  <DTS:Property
    DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
  <DTS:Variables>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{2BC52CDF-EB31-4362-9D38-96E9F58C47BE}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="&quot;This isn't SQL as we're not yet constraining extract SQL using From &amp; To date - We currently SELECT ALL FROM Staging VIEW for Products as opposed to an incremental date related load - this variable here for that purpose&quot;"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vExtractSQL">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="8">This isn't SQL as we're not yet constraining extract SQL using From &amp; To date - We currently SELECT ALL FROM Staging VIEW for Products as opposed to an incremental date related load - this variable here for that purpose</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:Description="This should be set to the PackageID of the package in the ManagmentDB tblPackage table"
      DTS:DTSID="{B7B9C488-1B2B-4EC0-A78B-7014DAE3D528}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPackageID">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">1118</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:Description="package execution ID returned from usp at start - used for comletion at end"
      DTS:DTSID="{8D185A78-654C-468C-9BEA-2BFD8471B9CC}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgExecID">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{8A604FDE-416C-444E-BD73-9CC599728D33}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="@[System::PackageID]"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgGUID">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="8">{47964379-22CB-4CC3-A5CD-3D01A1B8565C}</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{FF4A4DA8-A725-4075-9A72-FA72711E29B8}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgLastRunID">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{FF87FDEF-B219-4CA1-AF26-A22022025D17}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="@[System::PackageName]"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgName">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="8">1118_WMOS_Intk_FV</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{1D72E935-0B7A-4EBF-BA03-0EDC01D6526A}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="@[User::vPkgRowsBad_ILMAPPOINTMENTS] +  @[User::vPkgRowsBad_ASN_DTL] +  @[User::vPkgRowsBad_ASN]"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgRowsBad">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{A38F9327-CEC7-40A1-B14F-94545197FFB5}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgRowsBad_ASN">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{18F09461-E18D-41A9-BB02-3E49C13D196B}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgRowsBad_ASN_DTL">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{09363B5F-A496-49FA-B11C-FBB7C0E7FA74}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgRowsBad_ILMAPPOINTMENTS">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{3CECBAD0-E1DB-44A4-9081-F32831415669}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="@[User::vPkgRowsExtracted_ILMAPPOINTMENTS] +  @[User::vPkgRowsExtracted_ASN_DTL] +  @[User::vPkgRowsExtracted_ASN]"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgRowsExtracted">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{19441A99-2D0D-45AA-86DB-315A7E14830E}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgRowsExtracted_ASN">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{D13BC9F9-E34A-488C-A418-B8EF62AD7C84}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgRowsExtracted_ASN_DTL">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{0137A3E9-065A-4856-919B-B9E88F9CAC5B}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgRowsExtracted_ILMAPPOINTMENTS">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{B23A146C-67D5-494D-9247-2637FE78A143}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="@[User::vPkgRowsExtracted] -  @[User::vPkgRowsBad]"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgRowsInserted">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">0</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{E47A8B66-1D05-4CD4-A821-933AA955A97C}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="@[System::VersionGUID]"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPkgVersionGUID">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="8">{C43BDFD3-ED85-482F-8065-C07332E04CD1}</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{5B7EDEC7-8C77-47EF-AD02-B240407A6CB0}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="@[System::StartTime]"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vReportingEndDate">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="7">10/8/2019 1:50:43 PM</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{92B57286-BE9F-484B-A472-2338BF93F46A}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vReportingStartDate">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="7">6/1/2019</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{227CB535-8A39-405E-A3D5-AF96BC7F7E9C}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="&quot;SELECT &#xA;  asn.destination_facility_alias_id AS TO_WHSE,&#xA;  asn.tc_asn_id AS SHPMT_NBR,&#xA;  asn.actual_arrival_dttm AS ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME,&#xA;  asn.first_receipt_dttm AS FIRST_RCPT_DATE_TIME,&#xA;  asn.last_receipt_dttm AS LAST_RCPT_DATE_TIME,&#xA;  TO_CHAR(asn.last_updated_dttm, 'DD-MON-YY') AS MOD_DATE_TIME,&#xA;    CASE &#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status IN (5,10) THEN 0  -- CONVERT IN PLANNING &amp; OPEN TO ORDER PLACED&#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status = 20 THEN 10      -- CONVERT IN TRANSIT TO SHIPPED&#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status = 30 THEN 30      -- CONVERT RECEIVING STARTED TO DOM PO IN RECEIPT&#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status = 40 THEN 90      -- CONVERT RECEIVED VERIFED TO RECEIVED&#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status IN (50,60,70) THEN 99      -- CONVERT REFUSED, CANCELLED &amp; PENDING CANCELLED TO CANCELLED&#xA;  END AS STAT_CODE,&#xA;  CAST('FV' AS VARCHAR2(2)) AS SOURCE&#xA;FROM wms17seed.asn&#xA;WHERE&#xA;  SUBSTR(asn.tc_asn_id,1,3) NOT IN ('BLD','COL','DAC','FLD','SAM') &#xA;  AND TRUNC(asn.last_updated_dttm) &gt;= TRUNC(TO_DATE('&quot; +  (DT_WSTR,20) @[User::vReportingStartDate] + &quot;','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))&#xA;  AND TRUNC(asn.last_updated_dttm) &lt;= TRUNC(TO_DATE('&quot; + (DT_WSTR,20)  @[User::vReportingEndDate] + &quot;','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))&quot;"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vSQL_ASN">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="8">SELECT 
  asn.destination_facility_alias_id AS TO_WHSE,
  asn.tc_asn_id AS SHPMT_NBR,
  asn.actual_arrival_dttm AS ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME,
  asn.first_receipt_dttm AS FIRST_RCPT_DATE_TIME,
  asn.last_receipt_dttm AS LAST_RCPT_DATE_TIME,
  TO_CHAR(asn.last_updated_dttm, 'DD-MON-YY') AS MOD_DATE_TIME,
    CASE 
    WHEN asn.asn_status IN (5,10) THEN 0  -- CONVERT IN PLANNING &amp; OPEN TO ORDER PLACED
    WHEN asn.asn_status = 20 THEN 10      -- CONVERT IN TRANSIT TO SHIPPED
    WHEN asn.asn_status = 30 THEN 30      -- CONVERT RECEIVING STARTED TO DOM PO IN RECEIPT
    WHEN asn.asn_status = 40 THEN 90      -- CONVERT RECEIVED VERIFED TO RECEIVED
    WHEN asn.asn_status IN (50,60,70) THEN 99      -- CONVERT REFUSED, CANCELLED &amp; PENDING CANCELLED TO CANCELLED
  END AS STAT_CODE,
  CAST('FV' AS VARCHAR2(2)) AS SOURCE
FROM wms17seed.asn
WHERE
  SUBSTR(asn.tc_asn_id,1,3) NOT IN ('BLD','COL','DAC','FLD','SAM') 
  AND TRUNC(asn.last_updated_dttm) &gt;= TRUNC(TO_DATE('01/06/2019','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))
  AND TRUNC(asn.last_updated_dttm) &lt;= TRUNC(TO_DATE('08/10/2019 13:50:43','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'))</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{858CF7F6-58E8-4A53-A4E0-CDACFBBDC0E0}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="&quot;SELECT &#xA; asn.destination_facility_alias_id AS TO_WHSE,&#xA;  asn.tc_asn_id AS SHPMT_NBR,&#xA;  asn_dtl.seq_nbr AS SHPMT_SEQ_NBR,&#xA;  asn_dtl.sku_name AS SKU_BRCD,&#xA;  NVL(asn_dtl.shipped_lpn_count,0) AS CASES_SHPD,&#xA;  NVL(asn_dtl.shipped_qty,0) AS UNITS_SHPD,&#xA;  NVL(asn_dtl.received_lpn_count,0) AS CASES_RCVD,&#xA;  NVL(asn_dtl.received_qty,0) AS UNITS_RCVD,&#xA;  asn_dtl.tc_purchase_orders_id AS PO_NBR,&#xA;  asn_dtl.tc_po_line_id AS PO_LINE_NBR,&#xA;  TO_CHAR(asn_dtl.created_dttm, 'dd-MON-yy') AS CREATE_DATE_TIME,&#xA;  TO_CHAR(asn_dtl.last_updated_dttm, 'dd-MON-yy') AS MOD_DATE_TIME,&#xA;  CAST('FV' AS VARCHAR2(2)) AS SOURCE&#xA;FROM wms17seed.asn_detail asn_dtl&#xA;  INNER JOIN wms17seed.asn ON asn_dtl.asn_id = asn.asn_id &#xA;WHERE&#xA;  SUBSTR(asn.tc_asn_id,1,3) NOT IN ('BLD','COL','DAC','FLD','SAM')&#xA;  &#xA;AND asn_dtl.seq_nbr IS NOT NULL&#xA;&quot;"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vSQL_ASNDetail">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="8">SELECT 
 asn.destination_facility_alias_id AS TO_WHSE,
  asn.tc_asn_id AS SHPMT_NBR,
  asn_dtl.seq_nbr AS SHPMT_SEQ_NBR,
  asn_dtl.sku_name AS SKU_BRCD,
  NVL(asn_dtl.shipped_lpn_count,0) AS CASES_SHPD,
  NVL(asn_dtl.shipped_qty,0) AS UNITS_SHPD,
  NVL(asn_dtl.received_lpn_count,0) AS CASES_RCVD,
  NVL(asn_dtl.received_qty,0) AS UNITS_RCVD,
  asn_dtl.tc_purchase_orders_id AS PO_NBR,
  asn_dtl.tc_po_line_id AS PO_LINE_NBR,
  TO_CHAR(asn_dtl.created_dttm, 'dd-MON-yy') AS CREATE_DATE_TIME,
  TO_CHAR(asn_dtl.last_updated_dttm, 'dd-MON-yy') AS MOD_DATE_TIME,
  CAST('FV' AS VARCHAR2(2)) AS SOURCE
FROM wms17seed.asn_detail asn_dtl
  INNER JOIN wms17seed.asn ON asn_dtl.asn_id = asn.asn_id 
WHERE
  SUBSTR(asn.tc_asn_id,1,3) NOT IN ('BLD','COL','DAC','FLD','SAM')

AND asn_dtl.seq_nbr IS NOT NULL
</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
  </DTS:Variables>
  <DTS:Executables>
    <DTS:Executable
      DTS:refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob"
      DTS:CreationName="STOCK:SEQUENCE"
      DTS:Description="The work of the package"
      DTS:DTSID="{7EFE1902-6B7A-4D1A-A0C6-37479BCA7A94}"
      DTS:ExecutableType="STOCK:SEQUENCE"
      DTS:LocaleID="-1"
      DTS:ObjectName="SEQ_StagingJob">
      <DTS:Variables />
      <DTS:Executables>
        <DTS:Executable
          DTS:refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls"
          DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Pipeline"
          DTS:Description="Data Flow Task"
          DTS:DTSID="{5E1643D0-3ADB-43F3-A179-F5945057D703}"
          DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Pipeline"
          DTS:LocaleID="-1"
          DTS:ObjectName="dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls"
          DTS:TaskContact="Performs high-performance data extraction, transformation and loading;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) 2007 Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved;http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support/default.asp;1">
          <DTS:Variables />
          <DTS:ObjectData>
            <pipeline
              version="1">
              <components>
                <component
                  refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ASN"
                  componentClassID="Microsoft.RowCount"
                  contactInfo="Row Count;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0"
                  description="Counts rows as they pass through a data flow. For example, use the number of rows processed to determine whether or not to perform cleanup operations, or update text in an e-mail message to communicate processing status."
                  name="badrows_ASN">
                  <properties>
                    <property
                      dataType="System.String"
                      description="Specifies the variable to hold the row count."
                      name="VariableName">User::vPkgRowsBad_ASN</property>
                  </properties>
                  <inputs>
                    <input
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ASN.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]"
                      hasSideEffects="true"
                      name="Row Count Input 1">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </input>
                  </inputs>
                  <outputs>
                    <output
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ASN.Outputs[Row Count Output 1]"
                      name="Row Count Output 1"
                      synchronousInputId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ASN.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </output>
                  </outputs>
                </component>
                <component
                  refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ASN_DTL"
                  componentClassID="Microsoft.RowCount"
                  contactInfo="Row Count;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0"
                  description="Counts rows as they pass through a data flow. For example, use the number of rows processed to determine whether or not to perform cleanup operations, or update text in an e-mail message to communicate processing status."
                  name="badrows_ASN_DTL">
                  <properties>
                    <property
                      dataType="System.String"
                      description="Specifies the variable to hold the row count."
                      name="VariableName">User::vPkgRowsBad_ASN_DTL</property>
                  </properties>
                  <inputs>
                    <input
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ASN_DTL.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]"
                      hasSideEffects="true"
                      name="Row Count Input 1">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </input>
                  </inputs>
                  <outputs>
                    <output
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ASN_DTL.Outputs[Row Count Output 1]"
                      name="Row Count Output 1"
                      synchronousInputId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ASN_DTL.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </output>
                  </outputs>
                </component>
                <component
                  refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ILM_APPOINTMENTS"
                  componentClassID="Microsoft.RowCount"
                  contactInfo="Row Count;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0"
                  description="Counts rows as they pass through a data flow. For example, use the number of rows processed to determine whether or not to perform cleanup operations, or update text in an e-mail message to communicate processing status."
                  name="badrows_ILM_APPOINTMENTS">
                  <properties>
                    <property
                      dataType="System.String"
                      description="Specifies the variable to hold the row count."
                      name="VariableName">User::vPkgRowsBad_ILMAPPOINTMENTS</property>
                  </properties>
                  <inputs>
                    <input
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ILM_APPOINTMENTS.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]"
                      hasSideEffects="true"
                      name="Row Count Input 1">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </input>
                  </inputs>
                  <outputs>
                    <output
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ILM_APPOINTMENTS.Outputs[Row Count Output 1]"
                      name="Row Count Output 1"
                      synchronousInputId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\badrows_ILM_APPOINTMENTS.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </output>
                  </outputs>
                </component>
                <component
                  refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ASN"
                  componentClassID="Microsoft.RowCount"
                  contactInfo="Row Count;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0"
                  description="Counts rows as they pass through a data flow. For example, use the number of rows processed to determine whether or not to perform cleanup operations, or update text in an e-mail message to communicate processing status."
                  name="cnt_extrctd_ASN">
                  <properties>
                    <property
                      dataType="System.String"
                      description="Specifies the variable to hold the row count."
                      name="VariableName">User::vPkgRowsExtracted_ASN</property>
                  </properties>
                  <inputs>
                    <input
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ASN.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]"
                      hasSideEffects="true"
                      name="Row Count Input 1">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </input>
                  </inputs>
                  <outputs>
                    <output
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ASN.Outputs[Row Count Output 1]"
                      name="Row Count Output 1"
                      synchronousInputId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ASN.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </output>
                  </outputs>
                </component>
                <component
                  refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ASN_DTL"
                  componentClassID="Microsoft.RowCount"
                  contactInfo="Row Count;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0"
                  description="Counts rows as they pass through a data flow. For example, use the number of rows processed to determine whether or not to perform cleanup operations, or update text in an e-mail message to communicate processing status."
                  name="cnt_extrctd_ASN_DTL">
                  <properties>
                    <property
                      dataType="System.String"
                      description="Specifies the variable to hold the row count."
                      name="VariableName">User::vPkgRowsExtracted_ASN_DTL</property>
                  </properties>
                  <inputs>
                    <input
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ASN_DTL.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]"
                      hasSideEffects="true"
                      name="Row Count Input 1">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </input>
                  </inputs>
                  <outputs>
                    <output
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ASN_DTL.Outputs[Row Count Output 1]"
                      name="Row Count Output 1"
                      synchronousInputId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ASN_DTL.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </output>
                  </outputs>
                </component>
                <component
                  refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ILM_APPOINTMENTS"
                  componentClassID="Microsoft.RowCount"
                  contactInfo="Row Count;Microsoft Corporation; Microsoft SQL Server; (C) Microsoft Corporation; All Rights Reserved; http://www.microsoft.com/sql/support;0"
                  description="Counts rows as they pass through a data flow. For example, use the number of rows processed to determine whether or not to perform cleanup operations, or update text in an e-mail message to communicate processing status."
                  name="cnt_extrctd_ILM_APPOINTMENTS">
                  <properties>
                    <property
                      dataType="System.String"
                      description="Specifies the variable to hold the row count."
                      name="VariableName">User::vPkgRowsExtracted_ILMAPPOINTMENTS</property>
                  </properties>
                  <inputs>
                    <input
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ILM_APPOINTMENTS.Inputs[Row Count Input 1]"
                      hasSideEffects="true"
                      name="Row Count Input 1">
                      <externalMetadataColumns />
                    </input>
                  </inputs>
                  <outputs>
                    <output
                      refId="Package\SEQ_StagingJob\dft_LdFVPKMSStgTbls\cnt_extrctd_ILM_APPOINTMENTS.Outputs[Row Count Output 1]"
                      name="Row Count Output 1"
```

Comment: Please provide a *reduced* sample of your XML. The XPath with a leading ot `./properties`... will search below the current node, which might be the wrong place...

Comment: It seems that you are trying to query a SSIS package. They have somewhat complicated XML structure. As @Shnugo pointed out, without source XML, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: The xml file is too large to add to comments - can i email ?

Comment: You can edit your original post, and add the source XML

Comment: I have added what i could - had to cut it off mid point. Thanks in advance. NB in my SQL my from clause includes all nodes as a starting point IE FROM @xml.nodes('//*')

Comment: I think i need to refer to the current node not the context node within the [@DTS:ObjectName= part of the query. How would i do that ?

Comment: Mark, the XML you provide is not valid. We cannot copy-and-paste it to our machines. And the fragment you provide does not even contain the data you are asking for (or I did not understand your needs). Please try to set up a [mcve], something which can be copied into SSMS and runs with a simple F5.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @xml xml = N'

<DTS:Executable xmlns:DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts"
  DTS:refId="Package"
  DTS:CreationDate="2/16/2013 1:09:40 PM"
  DTS:CreationName="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:CreatorComputerName=""
  DTS:CreatorName=""
  DTS:DTSID="{47964379-22CB-4CC3-A5CD-3D01A1B8565C}"
  DTS:EnableConfig="True"
  DTS:ExecutableType="Microsoft.Package"
  DTS:LastModifiedProductVersion="15.0.1100.123"
  DTS:LocaleID="2057"
  DTS:ObjectName="1118_WMOS_Intk_FV"
  DTS:PackageType="5"
  DTS:VersionBuild="169"
  DTS:VersionGUID="{C43BDFD3-ED85-482F-8065-C07332E04CD1}">
  <DTS:Property
    DTS:Name="PackageFormatVersion">8</DTS:Property>
  <DTS:Variables>
    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{2BC52CDF-EB31-4362-9D38-96E9F58C47BE}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="&quot;This isn''t SQL as we''re not yet constraining extract SQL using From &amp; To date - We currently SELECT ALL FROM Staging VIEW for Products as opposed to an incremental date related load - this variable here for that purpose&quot;"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vExtractSQL">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="8">This isn''t SQL as we''re not yet constraining extract SQL using From &amp; To date - We currently SELECT ALL FROM Staging VIEW for Products as opposed to an incremental date related load - this variable here for that purpose</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>


    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:DTSID="{227CB535-8A39-405E-A3D5-AF96BC7F7E9C}"
      DTS:EvaluateAsExpression="True"
      DTS:Expression="&quot;SELECT &#xA;  asn.destination_facility_alias_id AS TO_WHSE,&#xA;  asn.tc_asn_id AS SHPMT_NBR,&#xA;  asn.actual_arrival_dttm AS ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME,&#xA;  asn.first_receipt_dttm AS FIRST_RCPT_DATE_TIME,&#xA;  asn.last_receipt_dttm AS LAST_RCPT_DATE_TIME,&#xA;  TO_CHAR(asn.last_updated_dttm, ''DD-MON-YY'') AS MOD_DATE_TIME,&#xA;    CASE &#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status IN (5,10) THEN 0  -- CONVERT IN PLANNING &amp; OPEN TO ORDER PLACED&#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status = 20 THEN 10      -- CONVERT IN TRANSIT TO SHIPPED&#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status = 30 THEN 30      -- CONVERT RECEIVING STARTED TO DOM PO IN RECEIPT&#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status = 40 THEN 90      -- CONVERT RECEIVED VERIFED TO RECEIVED&#xA;    WHEN asn.asn_status IN (50,60,70) THEN 99      -- CONVERT REFUSED, CANCELLED &amp; PENDING CANCELLED TO CANCELLED&#xA;  END AS STAT_CODE,&#xA;  CAST(''FV'' AS VARCHAR2(2)) AS SOURCE&#xA;FROM wms17seed.asn&#xA;WHERE&#xA;  SUBSTR(asn.tc_asn_id,1,3) NOT IN (''BLD'',''COL'',''DAC'',''FLD'',''SAM'') &#xA;  AND TRUNC(asn.last_updated_dttm) &gt;= TRUNC(TO_DATE(''&quot; +  (DT_WSTR,20) @[User::vReportingStartDate] + &quot;'',''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS''))&#xA;  AND TRUNC(asn.last_updated_dttm) &lt;= TRUNC(TO_DATE(''&quot; + (DT_WSTR,20)  @[User::vReportingEndDate] + &quot;'',''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS''))&quot;"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="2345"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vSQL_ASN">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="8">SELECT 
  asn.destination_facility_alias_id AS TO_WHSE,
  asn.tc_asn_id AS SHPMT_NBR,
  asn.actual_arrival_dttm AS ARRIVAL_DATE_TIME,
  asn.first_receipt_dttm AS FIRST_RCPT_DATE_TIME,
  asn.last_receipt_dttm AS LAST_RCPT_DATE_TIME,
  TO_CHAR(asn.last_updated_dttm, ''DD-MON-YY'') AS MOD_DATE_TIME,
    CASE 
    WHEN asn.asn_status IN (5,10) THEN 0  -- CONVERT IN PLANNING &amp; OPEN TO ORDER PLACED
    WHEN asn.asn_status = 20 THEN 10      -- CONVERT IN TRANSIT TO SHIPPED
    WHEN asn.asn_status = 30 THEN 30      -- CONVERT RECEIVING STARTED TO DOM PO IN RECEIPT
    WHEN asn.asn_status = 40 THEN 90      -- CONVERT RECEIVED VERIFED TO RECEIVED
    WHEN asn.asn_status IN (50,60,70) THEN 99      -- CONVERT REFUSED, CANCELLED &amp; PENDING CANCELLED TO CANCELLED
  END AS STAT_CODE,
  CAST(''FV'' AS VARCHAR2(2)) AS SOURCE
FROM wms17seed.asn
WHERE
  SUBSTR(asn.tc_asn_id,1,3) NOT IN (''BLD'',''COL'',''DAC'',''FLD'',''SAM'') 
  AND TRUNC(asn.last_updated_dttm) &gt;= TRUNC(TO_DATE(''01/06/2019'',''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS''))
  AND TRUNC(asn.last_updated_dttm) &lt;= TRUNC(TO_DATE(''08/10/2019 13:50:43'',''DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS''))</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>    



    <DTS:Variable
      DTS:CreationName=""
      DTS:Description="This should be set to the PackageID of the package in the ManagmentDB tblPackage table"
      DTS:DTSID="{B7B9C488-1B2B-4EC0-A78B-7014DAE3D528}"
      DTS:IncludeInDebugDump="6789"
      DTS:Namespace="User"
      DTS:ObjectName="vPackageID">
      <DTS:VariableValue
        DTS:DataType="3">1118</DTS:VariableValue>
    </DTS:Variable>
   </DTS:Variables>
    </DTS:Executable>  
';

select @xml.value('declare namespace DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts";
(//DTS:Variables/DTS:Variable[@DTS:ObjectName="vSQL_ASN"]/DTS:VariableValue)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)');

select @xml.value('declare namespace DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts";
(//DTS:Variables/DTS:Variable[@DTS:ObjectName="vExtractSQL"]/DTS:VariableValue)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)');

select @xml.value('declare namespace DTS="www.microsoft.com/SqlServer/Dts";
(//DTS:Variables/DTS:Variable[@DTS:ObjectName=sql:column("drv.property")]/DTS:VariableValue)[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
from
(values('vSQL_ASN'),('vExtractSQL')) as drv(property);
```